# When trying to use Mockito to unit test sending email, I create a multipartemail object in the function, but the test fails, why?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

This is my unit testing code.

```
 public class StatsTest extends AbstractTestCase {
@Mock 
//EmailInfo mockMetricsEmail = Mockito.mock(EmailInfo.class);
//EmailSenderImpl mockEmailSenderImpl = Mockito.mock(EmailSenderImpl.class);
private MultiPartEmail mockMultiPartEmail = Mockito.mock(HtmlEmail.class); 

private static final String testEmailBody = "This is the test email body.";
private static final String testSender = "seemakur@amazon.com"; 
private static final String testRecipient = ("seemakur@amazon.com");
private static final String testEmailSubject = "subject";
private static final String testHostName = "seemakur.desktop.amazon.com";
private static final MultiPartEmail testHtmlEmail = new HtmlEmail();

EmailSenderImpl emailSenderImplObj = new EmailSenderImpl();
EmailInfo emailInfoObj = new EmailInfo(testEmailBody, testSender, testRecipient, testEmailSubject, testHostName, testHtmlEmail);



@Before
public void setUp() throws Throwable {
    super.setUp();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); // will instantiate "mockMultiPartEmail"
    // instantiate our class under test
}

@Test(expected = EmailException.class)
public void testSendEmail() throws EmailException, IOException {

    MultiPartEmail testMultiPartEmail = Mockito.spy(new HtmlEmail());
    Mockito.doReturn(mockMultiPartEmail).when(emailInfoObj).getMultiPartEmail(); //stub(spy.getMultiPartEmail()).toReturn(mockMultiPartEmail);
    Mockito.when(mockMultiPartEmail.send()).thenThrow(new EmailException("Failed on multipartEmail.send(), hence could not send the email."));

    // when the method under test is called
    try {
        //testEmailSenderImplObj.sendHtmlTableAsEmail(testMetricsEmail);
        emailSenderImplObj.sendHtmlTableAsEmail(emailInfoObj); //inject mock & invoke what to test  
        fail("Expecting EmailException");
    }catch(EmailException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Mockito.verify(mockMultiPartEmail).send();Mockito.doReturn(mockMultiPartEmail).when(emailInfoObj).getMultiPartEmail(); //stub(spy.getMultiPartEmail()).toReturn(mockMultiPartEmail);

}

   }
```

i have three classes associated with this email function:
firstly below is emailInfo data object

```
   @Data
   public class EmailInfo {
private String emailBody;
private String senderEmail;
private String receiversEmails;
private String emailSubject;
private String hostName;
    private MultiPartEmail multiPartEmail;

public EmailInfo(String emailBody, String senderEmail, String receiversEmails, String emailSubject, String hostName, MultiPartEmail multiPartEmail) {

    this.setEmailBody(emailBody);
    this.setSenderEmail(senderEmail);
    this.setReceiversEmails(receiversEmails);
    this.setEmailSubject(emailSubject);
    this.setHostName(hostName);
    this.setMultiPartEmail(multiPartEmail);
}

public String getSenderEmail() {
    return senderEmail;
}
public void setSenderEmail(String senderEmail) {
    this.senderEmail = senderEmail;
}

public String getEmailBody() {
    return emailBody;
}
public void setEmailBody(String emailBody) {
    this.emailBody = emailBody;
}


public String getReceiversEmails() {
    return receiversEmails;
}
public void setReceiversEmails(String receiversEmails2) {
    this.receiversEmails = receiversEmails2;
}


public String getEmailSubject() {
    return emailSubject;
}
public void setEmailSubject(String emailSubject) {
    this.emailSubject = emailSubject;
}


public String getHostName() {
    return hostName;
}
public void setHostName(String hostName) {
    this.hostName = hostName;
}

public MultiPartEmail getMultiPartEmail() {
    return multiPartEmail;
}

public void setMultiPartEmail(MultiPartEmail multiPartEmail) {
    this.multiPartEmail = multiPartEmail;
}

    }
```

second class: EmailSenderImpl.java

```
     public class EmailSenderImpl implements EmailSender{

     // public MultiPartEmail getEmail(){
     //     return multiPartEmail;
     // }
     // 
     // public void setEmail(MultiPartEmail multiPartEmail){
     //     this.multiPartEmail = multiPartEmail;
     // }

    public void sendHtmlTableAsEmail(EmailInfo emailInfo)throws IOException, EmailException{
    MultiPartEmail multiPartEmail = new HtmlEmail();
    multiPartEmail.setHostName(emailInfo.getHostName());
    multiPartEmail.addTo(emailInfo.getReceiversEmails());
    multiPartEmail.setFrom(emailInfo.getSenderEmail());
    multiPartEmail.setSubject(emailInfo.getEmailSubject());
    multiPartEmail.setMsg((emailInfo.getEmailBody()).toString());
    multiPartEmail.send();
}
```

}

lastly the EMailSender.java interface.

```
     public interface EmailSender{
public abstract void sendHtmlTableAsEmail(EmailInfo emailInfo)throws IOException, EmailException;
     }
```

I reason I have so many classes for one simple function is because i cannot use static methods, and i have to separate "business logic" from "function logic." And I need to have interfaces, that is necessary. If there is a better way to organize this, please let me know.

Now when I run the unit test, it fails on the line: "Mockito.doReturn(mockMultiPartEmail).when(emailInfoObj).getMultiPartEmail(); //stub(spy.getMultiPartEmail()).toReturn(mockMultiPartEmail);
        ");"

the error reads: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException

Comment: Instanciate the emailInfoObj as a mock object, please consider posting the complete stacktrace next time

Comment: emailInfo is a class that I wrote, so I don't have to mock it right? I only need to mock multiPart Email, right?

Here is the complete stack trace:
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException> but was<org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException>
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:31)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
 at

Comment: Please do not add additional information regarding your question as comments, you should edit your question. Please read: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1 - you have to mock objects if you want to add behavior, even if you wrote them yourself

Comment: now it is failing on this line: "fail("Expecting EmailException");"

Comment: my code now is this: 

MultiPartEmail testMultiPartEmail = Mockito.spy(new HtmlEmail());
  Mockito.doReturn(mockMultiPartEmail).when(mockMetricsEmail).getMultiPartEmail(); //stub(spy.getMultiPartEmail()).toReturn(mockMultiPartEmail);
  emailInfoObj.setMultiPartEmail(mockMultiPartEmail);
  // when the method under test is called
  try {
   //testEmailSenderImplObj.sendHtmlTableAsEmail(testMetricsEmail);
   emailSenderImplObj.sendHtmlTableAsEmail(emailInfoObj); //inject mock & invoke what to test

Comment: Mockito.when((emailInfoObj.getMultiPartEmail().send())).thenThrow(new EmailException("Failed on multipartEmail.send(), hence could not send the email."));
   fail("Expecting EmailException");
  }catch(EmailException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  Mockito.verify(mockMultiPartEmail).send();

Comment: **Please do not add additional information regarding your question as comments** you should edit your question. People attempting to help you will have a very hard time reading your code. You understand that, right?

Comment: OP - can you please edit your question so that it has your actual code and the stack trace?    An example that I can actually directly copy and paste to my IDE would be best.  It's impossible to find the issue with your code if I have to read your question and three different comments to understand what your code actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original code, your problem is that on this line

```
Mockito.doReturn(mockMultiPartEmail).when(emailInfoObj).getMultiPartEmail();
```

you are trying to stub the behaviour of the created with this line

```
EmailInfo emailInfoObj = new EmailInfo(testEmailBody, testSender, testRecipient, testEmailSubject, testHostName, testHtmlEmail);
```

But this is not a mock or a spy.  Mockito only lets you stub the behaviour of mocks and spies, not just arbitrary objects.

I can't tell whether you still have this issue after subsequent updates, as it's impossible to read code that's embedded in comments.